# Conditionally applying css to mat form field

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular7, angular8

I am working on an angular application and I am using mat form fields in it. For changing color of botttom border of mat form field I am using mat-form-field-ripple css which is inbuilt for mat form field. CSS is as follows.

```
.mat-form-field-ripple {
    background-color: #f9c940!important;
}
```

When I use this CSS, it automatically gets applied to all form fields. I have to apply #f9c940 color in mat-form-filed-ripple in when one condition is true and a different color when another condition is true. My mat form field code is as follows:

```
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                            <mat-label [ngClass]="{}">Name</mat-label>
                            <input formControlName="Name" readonly>
                        </mat-form-field>
```

I was trying to do it using ngClass as shown above but not getting it. How can I do that?

Comment: I just gave  a example. Anyone who knows angular knows what it does. Just trying to explain what I was trying

Answer (score 1):

ngClass doesn't work with `<mat-form-field>`. Use this syntax-

```
<mat-form-field [class.mat-form-field-invalid]="booleanVariable">
```

and in the .ts file, you can conditionally update the `booleanVariable`

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own CSS class:

```
.mat-form-field-ripple {
    //your standard styling,
}

.myBackgroundColor {
    background-color: #f9c940!important;
// add this selector below the .mat-form-field-ripple selector so that it will override..
}
```

Then apply it conditionally to your label:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label [ngClass]="{'myBackgroundColor': mycheck}">Name</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="Name" readonly>
</mat-form-field>
```

In your component you have the expression it is based on:

```
mycheck = true; // you will modify this true to any expression that is transformable to a boolean. If true, your class is applied, if false then not..
```

Comment: how I can use mat-form-field-ripple in this? contiionally

Comment: @zaib7777 you can apply your general styles with the .mat-form-field-ripple selector in your CSS. But the color you sometimes want is not in that selector (since that would apply to all the elements), it's in another selector that you apply conditionally to your fields in order to override the general style. I've updated my answer to show you

Answer (score 0):

You can apply classes conditionally like this:

```
<mat-label [ngClass]="{'your-class': foo=='foo', 'your-class-another':bar=='bar' }">
    Name
</mat-label>
```

Comment: nops normal ngClass condtions not working in this. Already tried this

Comment: @zaib7777 could you create a stackblitz example?