# Mat form field color changing

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9

I am working on angular application and I have got similar problem mentioned on below two links

[Conditionally applying css to mat form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61307041/conditionally-applying-css-to-mat-form-field)
[Changing color of mat form ripple conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62664786/changing-color-of-mat-form-ripple-conditionally)

But solutions suggested on both the links doesn't work. Do anyone know a better solution for this?

Comment: How the solutions not worked for you? what is your exact requirement? Can you post the issue reproducible stackblitz :)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply inline CSS in mat-form-field as i have done in example.
**style="color:red"**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="legacy" style="color:red">
 <mat-label>Legacy form field</mat-label>
 <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
 <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
 <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello i change the color of my mat-form-field with next steps

Dont forget this line on the component who was present the mat-form-field :

```
@Component({
  ...,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

And after you change different element color white :

**Cursor color :**

```
.mat-input-element {
   caret-color: gray;
}
```

**Outline color :**

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
    color: rgba($color: #FFFFFF, $alpha: 0.3);
}
```

**Outline focused color :**

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-focused .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
    color: rgba($color: #FFFFFF, $alpha: 0.8);
}
```

**Label color :**

```
mat-label{
    color:rgba($color: #FFFFFF, $alpha: 0.8);
}
```